# How can two $C^1$ transition map form a $C^{\infty}$ compatible charts?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Two charts $(U,\phi : U → R^n)$, $(V,\psi: V → R^n)$ of a topological
manifold are $C^{\infty}$ compatible if the two maps: $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ and $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ are $C^{\infty}$ class.

Now, if we consider a circle $S^1$ in a complex plane and define two open set as:
\begin{align}
U_1 &= \{e^{it} \in \mathbb{C}| -\pi <t < \pi \}, \\
U_2 &= \{e^{it} \in \mathbb{C}| 0 <t < 2\pi \}
\end{align}
Define: $\phi_1(e^{it}) = t, -\pi < t < \pi$ and $\phi_2(e^{it}) = t, 0 < t < 2\pi$. Then we can show that:$(\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1})(t) = t \text{ for }t \in (0,\pi)$ and $(\phi_1 \circ \phi_2^{-1})(t) = t \text{ for }t \in (0,\pi)$.

Therefore $(U_1,\phi_1)$ and $(U_2,\phi_2)$ are $C^{\infty}$ compatible charts and form a $C^{\infty}$ atlas. This example is taken from "An introduction to manifolds" by Loring W.Tu (chapter-2, pg-50, example:5.7). My question is I think $\phi_1 \circ \phi_2^{-1}$ and $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}$ are in $C^1$ class, if then how can it is $C^{\infty}$ compatible.

I am quite new in this topic. Please forgive me, if it is a very silly question.

Comment: These two transition maps are of class $\mathcal{C}^1$, yes, but they are also of class $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. Why wouldn't they?

Comment: for class $C^{\infty}$, they needed to be differentiable for all degrees but for above maps there are only exist first order differentiation, rest of them will be zeros.

Comment: Why would not $t \mapsto t$  be differentiable at all orders? Are you saying that constant functions (and particularly the zero function) are not differentiable?

Comment: I think I understand my mistake now. You are saying that, the constant function will give zero output but this also means that the differentiation exists for infinite time.

Comment: Differentiating zero gives zero, which is again differentiable and gives, after differentiation, zero, *etc*.

Comment: @Didier Thanks, I get it.

Comment: I think, you also incorrectly computed the transition maps (they are not the identity).